# VBA Turn Column with Date and Time to 24hrs (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, data-conversion

I have a date & time column with many rows that look like this:

11/11/19 3:54PM

11/11/19 5:33AM

I would like to basically leave the dates alone but just change the times in place to 24 hour and deleting the am or pm and add G at the end. Like this:

11/11/19 15:54G

11/11/19 05:33G

Is there a simple way to do this or do i have to split date and time over 2 columns, do the conversion then concatenate.

Thanks.

I tried to do this thru cell formatting

```vb
Sub Converter()

Dim Focus As String

With ActiveSheet
Range("A3:A100").Select

Do
Focus = Format$(ActiveCell, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")

ActiveCell.Value = Focus
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))

End With


End Sub
```

I would like to achieve this in vb

Comment: I assume the only issue is that the format is coming out incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close: `Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm") & "G"`

You could use `h:mmG` in the format, but that is less clear for others looking in the future.

Comment: That works but is always missing the forward slashes in the date, if i use something else like a dash it's fine, 11-11-19 15:54G